# How to have UV Unwrap move one island only as a whole and keep it's vertices in place, relative to the island?

Tags: mesh, uv

I'm trying to unwrap a very complex mesh, more specifically the panel of an airplane, from which I have extruded sunk-in patches for the instruments. To make it simple I did Project from View for the flat part of the panel including the sunk parts and pinned all the vertices that are part of the sunk-in patches for the instruments. Then I selected everything in the 3D view and did a normal Unwrap. This resulted in the other two islands that are also part of the mesh to be unwrapped correctly themselves, but they're now at a different scale and overlap the Project from View'ed island:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXhj0.png]

Now I thought if I could somehow pin the red colored vertices onto the island instead of glueing the vertices to their absolute UV position, I could let Unwrap let bring everything to the right size and position instead of having to do it manually. Is this possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinning will always keep the vertex at its absolute position. You don't need to "glue" these faces as they are already part of the same island. You can select all the islands you want to automatically position, then click UV > Pack Islands. If you want more resolution (more space in texture space) for a certain island. Simply select an island, scale up and repack. You can select islands with <kbd>L</kbd>. Make sure UV> Constrain to Image Bounds is unchecked to making scaling easier.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Well, I hoped to be able to just tell the Unwrap which faces it should not re-unwrap but just move, rotate and scale around, but Pack Islands is something which looks quite useful. Does it only move the islands or can it also scale and rotate them if they don't fit the image just by moving ?

Comment: Pack islands will Move and Scale, there's a toggle option for Rotation.